# What is NSExceptionDomains and when should I use it?

Tags: ios, app-transport-security

New to iOS with networking programming.

Please any one help to understand that?

```
  <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key><!-- your_remote_server.com / localhost --></key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    <!-- add more domain here -->
    </dict>
```

Comment: Those two settings seem kind of contradictory: Allow unencrypted HTTP, but also require stronger encryption on HTTPS.

Comment: Read the [documentation on NSAppTransportSecurity](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW33)

Comment: @rmaddy are you still allowed to submit to App store and have `NSExceptionDomains` enabled?

Answer (score 5):

Apple introduced App Transport Security (ATS) and requires apps to have a secure connection for server communications. As a temporary measure, until all apps and servers can comply with the requirements, they allow you to define exceptions to the security requirements. You can read more here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW35

Comment: This also means: You should *not* use this if you can fix transport security properly.

Comment: True, you should consider exceptions temporary and remove exceptions as soon as you can